# Sort results where "seen" matches 2

Tags: laravel

I have a table for stories with fields id, user_id, file_name, seen (1-2)

```
Stories: id, user_id, file_name, seen
```

I would like to create a list that takes all the stories but with a primary order where seen corresponds to 2 (still to be seen then)

I have this simple query as a test, what should I do?

```
$users = App\Models\User::whereHas('stories', function ($query) {

})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

```
$users = App\Models\User::whereHas('stories')->with(['stories' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy(DB::raw('stories.seen=2'), 'desc')
}])->get();
```

Or

```
$users = App\Models\User::whereHas('stories')
    ->select('*')
    ->join('stories', 'stories.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('stories.seen=2'), 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try another solution